# Executor Service task executing twice in spring boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, executorservice

I have a Spring Boot application which has a task currently set to run daily and execute a task but it looks like it is running twice and resulting in unintended side effects. The task has to write to a database and as a result of running twice am getting an error on the db.

This issue relates to deployment as when I run it locally it works. If I start up another instance of the same app locally am able to simulate the error. This suggests something in my container is registering the task twice.

```
 private void syncData(DatasetProperties dataset, EndPointSync lastSyncResult) {

    inProgressSyncs.addDataSet(dataset.getName());

    LocalDateTime currentSyncTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    DatasetSynchronizationResult currentSyncResult;
    Future<DatasetSynchronizationResult> resultFuture = datasetSynchronizationExecutorService
        .submit(getCallableForDataset(dataset, lastSyncResult, currentSyncTime));

    try {
      currentSyncResult = resultFuture.get();
    } catch (CancellationException | ExecutionException ex) {
      currentSyncResult = DatasetSynchronizationResult
          .unexpectedError(dataset.getName(), currentSyncTime);
      datasetSynchronizationLogger.logUnexpectedException(log, dataset, ex);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
      currentSyncResult = DatasetSynchronizationResult
          .unexpectedError(dataset.getName(), currentSyncTime);
      datasetSynchronizationLogger.logUnexpectedException(log, dataset, ex);
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }

    inProgressSyncs.removeDataSet(dataset.getName());
    datasetSynchronizationLogger.logDatasetSynchronizationResult(
        log, lastSyncResult, currentSyncResult);
    updateSynchronizationResult(dataset, lastSyncResult, currentSyncResult);
  }
```

This is the spring boot error message shown:

```
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
      at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:257)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:223)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:540)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:746)
```

Comment: How the syncData method is scheduled?

Comment: Am using CronTrigger class which is accepting parameters. However - the format we have used in Spring boot is * 0 * * * * and it seems like format should actually be 0 0 * * * * . Could that possibly make a difference?